# 'EstablishmentType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

I get the following error and can not find how to fix it

> Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:   'EstablishmentType' object
>   is not iterable

**Class Serializer:**

```
class TransactionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    establishment_from_id = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='establishment_type', read_only=True, many=True)

class Meta:
    model = Transaction
    fields = ('id', 'created_date', 'updated_date','establishment_from_id', 'quantity', 'owner_id', 'quantity_missing', 'gps_longitude', 'gps_latitude', 'gps_accuracy', 'type')
```

**Models**

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    created_date = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField()
    establishment_from_id = models.ForeignKey(EstablishmentType, related_name="establishment_from")
    establishment_to_id = models.ForeignKey(EstablishmentType, related_name="establishment_to")
    quantity = models.FloatField()
    owner_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    quantity_missing = models.FloatField()
    status = models.ForeignKey(TransactionStatus)
    gps_longitude = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    gps_latitude = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    gps_accuracy = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    type = models.FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class EstablishmentType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    #created_by = CreatingUserField(related_name="created_categories")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try taking out the `many=True` from the Serializer. The establishment_from_id is a FK rather than an M2M, thus for each instance it's only going to have one value. If this were the serializers for `EstablishmentType` then it would make sense to have a `many=True`

Comment: @PaulCould thanks for your answer ! 

Remove what you said and now selling me the following mistake:

Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "establishment_type". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.

Comment: Do you have a serializer for `EstablishmentType`? If not you need to make one, if so then make sure that all the ViewSets are hooked up to Routers and those routers are included in your urls.py.